# BigQuery - Count the number of rows until a specific row is reached

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm new to coding and stackoverflow so apologies if my questions sounds stupid.

I have Google Analytics data in BigQuery which I'm trying to draw insights from.

What I'm trying to do is look at each user and their behaviour as they browse.

Specifically, I want to count the number of 'product view' events before their FIRST 'add to cart' event.

In the attached example, its sorted by timestamp ascending and the value returned would be 12 'product view' events before their first 'add to cart' event.

How would I get the value for every individual user? Code used is below:

```
SELECT 
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', Date) AS Date,
  fullVisitorId as UserID,
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction as eventaction,
FROM `table_name`, UNNEST (hits) AS hits
WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventCategory IS NOT NULL
  AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Ecommerce'
  AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction IN ('Product View', 'Add to Cart')
ORDER BY hits.time ASC
```

Thank you in advance.

[image: Query results]

Comment: Edit our question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to count the number of 'product view' events before their FIRST 'add to cart' event.

You can calculate this value using window functions:

```
SELECT userId, seqnum - 1
FROM (SELECT t.*, hits,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ut.userId ORDER BY h.time) as seqnum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ut.userId, eventAction ORDER BY h.time) as seqnum_ea
      FROM `table_name` t CROSS JOIN
           UNNEST(t.hits) AS hits
      WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventCategory IS NOT NULL AND
            hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Ecommerce' AND
            hits.eventInfo.eventAction IN ('Product View', 'Add to Cart')
     ) t
WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Add to Cart' AND seqnum_ea = 1;
```

Comment: shouldnt the column be (seqnum-1)